# Define a type for all possible object property types

Tags: typescript

When we hover over the `typeof` for an arbitrary object property, we see the list of possible types:

`"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"`

[image]

How can we capture that list as a user-defined `type`, without hard coding each one like this:

```
type ObjectPropertyType =
    string |
    number |
    bigint |
    boolean |
    symbol |
    undefined |
    object |
    Function;
```

Comment: This sent me down a rabbit hole of wonder how primitive types are implemented in TypeScript. I have no idea.... Does `ObjectPropertyType` that you defined behave different than `any`? It seems to me that because `object` is in that list, the behaviour will be the same

Comment: I think the problem here is a confusion over what typeof is: this isn't coming from TS, it's a JS builtin. It doesn't return types, it returns a string representing a type known in JS. This list is just the possible values of typeof in JS.

Comment: Particularly note that `"string" | "number"` is not the same as `string | number`. The former is a type union of string literal types, the latter is a type union of primitive types.

Comment: @IngoBürk To be clear, I understand the difference between `'string'` and `string`. I appreciate that I could have made that more clear in the question.

Comment: @Leon Yes. `any` behaves slightly differently than `ObjectPropertyType` does. Try these two: `type NotString1 = Exclude<any, string>` vs `type NotString2 = Exclude<ObjectPropertyType, string>` and see the resultant type.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` is a JavaScript builtin that returns the (runtime!) type of a variable as a string(!). The Typescript types are quite different from this, they just have the same name because TypeScript was designed to be close to JavaScript here.

In particular, the types `"string" | "number"` and `string | number` are *not* the same. The values `"Hello"` and `42` can be assigned to the latter, but not the former.

The confusion here is that `typeof` comes from JS and only returns string representations of types defined in JavaScript; this has nothing to do with TypeScript at all. All that TypeScript does is it knows the possible values and thus returns a type union of all these values to have the best possible typing.

So to answer the question of

> How can we capture that list as a user-defined type

These types aren't the same to begin with. For example, `typeof null === "object"`, so even the TypeScript type `null` would have to appear in that list. In fact, the list of types that can produce any of these values when typeof is applied to a variable of that type is simply `any`, so

```
type ObjectPropertyType = any;
```

Comment: In TS3.0 and up I would suggest using [`unknown`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-unknown-top-type) instead of `any`.

Comment: @jcalz Agreed, but the type inference as of now of `const test = obj["x"]` with `declare const obj: object` is `test: any`, not `test: unknown`.

Comment: What you wrote is true but unfortunately doesn't answer my question. Apologies for not making my question clear. What I am seeking is a type union such as `string | number | ...` not of `'string' | 'number' | ...`. I already understand that the name of a type is not the same as the type itself, and I could have made that more clear in my original question.

Comment: `any` behaves slightly differently than `ObjectPropertyType` does in my question. Try these two: `type NotString1 = Exclude<any, string>` vs `type NotString2 = Exclude<ObjectPropertyType, string>` and see the resultant type.

Comment: @jcalz `unknown` also behaves differently with `Exclude` just like `any` does in the above example.

Comment: As a fiddle: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ObjectPropertyValue%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20string%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20number%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bigint%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20boolean%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20symbol%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20undefined%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20object%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Function%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NotString1%20%3D%20Exclude%3Cany%2C%20string%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NotString2%20%3D%20Exclude%3CObjectPropertyValue%2C%20string%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NotString3%20%3D%20Exclude%3Cunknown%2C%20string%3E%3B%0D%0A

Comment: As I pointed out, null is of type object when using `typeof` even though the TS type is `null`. So your type would have to be a type union of every possible type, which is essentially `any`. You haven't once mentioned `Exclude` in your question, so I'm not assuming this is an XY problem.

Comment: I know `Exclude` isn't part of my question; it is in the comments here to illustrate that, on the one hand, `any` is very similar to `ObjectPropertyType`, but on the other hand, it has some key differences.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to give up as I don't understand the question anymore. It's not clear what you want to do with this nor what exactly it is you need (I've pointed out null multiple times now to no avail). You're asking to convert oranges to apples as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's fair enough... it's a hard thing for me to explain. Apologies for not being more clear. I want to create `ObjectPropertyType` without hard coding the type union.